# Any Way to monitor JMX Servers with NetIq?

Tags: windows, monitoring, jmx

I ask this question after a search in the site, there's many JMX questions but I think no one with a NetIq involved.

In the documentation of NetIq, There's no "module" to check JMX, but I have seen that u can make "custom" modules and "custom" scripts, in Perl and VbScript.

The question is if anyone with more experience than me on NetIq, has made any custom script or module to check JMX.

I look on technet too, for a JMX Api for Windos Shell or Powershell with no luck.

Of course, JMX is much more powerfull, but what I really need is to "monitor" some values inside NetIq, because we cant install Nagios, Cacti, Hyperic or any other monitor software but NetIq.

Thanks.

Comment: Have searched in the stack exchange site, there's many ways to connect to jmx (as I already know). If any of those methods can be integrated in NetIq, it will work. I'm talking about Groove, jmx4perl and similar. Thanks

Comment: Still Looking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the Community Experience Manager at Qmunity, NetIQ's online community. Have you asked the NetIQ user community, specifically the [NetIQ AppManager Forum](http://community.netiq.com/forums/30.aspx) - I know someone could answer you there.

Comment: Will do. I have searched and asked to the NetIq tech that we have in the firm (more than 1 thousand servers monitored) and they dont know. Checking the forum now. Any other response?

Comment: Registered. I havent access to that particular forum. Have access to others.